# Android Remote Desktop Access

Tags: java, android, remote-desktop, rdp

I am using ProperJavaRDP,its working fine in java.When move to convert java to android struggling with receiving byte arrays.The size of the byte array changing in android and java.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please post your code, it would help us debug the situation a little better.

Comment: Send Request
  
  https://github.com/kohsuke/properjavardp/blob/master/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#L369
  
  Send
    
  https://github.com/kohsuke/properjavardp/blob/master/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#L185
  
  
  Receive
  
  https://github.com/kohsuke/properjavardp/blob/master/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#L246

Comment: You can also check Android RDP Client                                Send Request
 http://code.google.com/p/android-rdp-client/source/browse/trunk/androidRDPClient/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#370

Send 

http://code.google.com/p/android-rdp-client/source/browse/trunk/androidRDPClient/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#186

Receive

http://code.google.com/p/android-rdp-client/source/browse/trunk/androidRDPClient/src/net/propero/rdp/ISO.java#247

Comment: @Otra:Is any thing you found newly,let me know.Still i am struggling to do the remote access process?